# Why my MVC view passes null but not the value it has?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

1. View shows proper value (OrderId = 3):

   ```
    // GET:
   public ActionResult ConfirmOrder()
   {

       //simplified code here
       var model = new ConfirmOrderViewModel()
       {
           OrderId = 3,
       };

       return View(model);
   }
   ```
2. View works fine one way (value visible on the screen) Html-part below:

   ```
   @model Test.Models.Views.ConfirmOrderViewModel
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "My title";
   }

   <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


   @using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmOrder", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { 
   @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
   {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


   <div class="row" style="padding:10px; margin:15px">
        <div>
             <div class="col-sm-3">
                  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderId)
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
   ```

   ```
   }
   ```

   3. ConfirmOrderViewModel class looks like this:

      ```
      public class ConfirmOrderViewModel
      {
             public int OrderId { get; set; }
      }
      ```

**4. But when it comes to post it back, only null I'm having:**

```
        // POST:
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ConfirmOrder(ConfirmOrderViewModel ViewModel)
        {
           //at this moment: ViewModel.OrderId = null 
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Controller Name is ok, Methods works... no errors. Just null after clicking the OK button on page. What can cause bad model binding here?

Comment: You have not generated any form controls for your model (`DisplayFor()` does not generate an input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DisplayFor` helper method will just render the value of the `OrderId` property. As the name suggests, It is more for displaying to the user. If you want the value for `OrderId` to be posted to the http post action method, you need to keep that in in a form field inside the form.

You can keep in a hidden field inside the `form`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmOrder", "Client"))
{  
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OrderId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.OrderId)
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
}
```